# Why does my Intuit QBO SDK purchase order not have Copy To Bill Action option in Vendor Transaction list?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online, purchase-order

When I add an Intuit Quickbooks Online purchase order with SDK v3, it shows up (in their online interface) under the assigned Vendor's transaction list appropriately as a Purchase Order.  Under the Action column, the only options are Print or Copy.  If I open the Purchase Order and save it without changing anything, the Action column options then include Send, Copy To Bill, Print and Copy.  There are no errors adding the PO.  Logging shows the PO was added successfully.  Why isn't the Copy To Bill option available immediately after it is added?  Here is a copy of the request.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
  <DocNumber>1</DocNumber>
  <TxnDate>2015-01-30</TxnDate>
  <Line>
    <Description>Fountain Pump</Description>
    <Amount>10</Amount>
    <DetailType>ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail</DetailType>
    <ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail>
      <ItemRef>11</ItemRef>
      <UnitPrice>10</UnitPrice>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <CustomerRef>63</CustomerRef>
    </ItemBasedExpenseLineDetail>
  </Line>
  <VendorRef>30</VendorRef>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct request-

```
<PurchaseOrder xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
  <TxnDate>2015-02-02</TxnDate>
  <CurrencyRef name="United States Dollar">USD</CurrencyRef>
  <Line>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Amount>45.00</Amount>
    <DetailType>AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail</DetailType>
    <AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
      <AccountRef name="Purchases">17</AccountRef>
      <BillableStatus>NotBillable</BillableStatus>
      <TaxCodeRef>NON</TaxCodeRef>
    </AccountBasedExpenseLineDetail>
  </Line>
  <VendorRef name="fffaltu">9</VendorRef>
  <APAccountRef name="Name_a0a0e">10</APAccountRef>
  <TotalAmt>45.00</TotalAmt>
  <VendorAddr>
    <Id>208</Id>
    <Line1>fffaltu</Line1>
    <Line2>aaaxasxsaxasx</Line2>
  </VendorAddr>
  <ShipAddr>
    <Id>209</Id>
    <Line1>QBO_US_Plus_D49a58</Line1>
    <Line2>yyxw</Line2>
    <Line3>eee, AK  56033 US</Line3>
  </ShipAddr>
  <POStatus>Open</POStatus>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

I tried multiple times to replicate your use case.
If I do not send the POStatus then only this issue happens.
Might be a bug. I will report it.
Please send the POStatus to overcome this issue.

Comment: Adding the POStatus fixed the issue.  Thank you.